# Regex vs readline for text processing

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, readline

I have a text to process (router output) and generate useful data structure (dictionary having keys as iface name and values as packet counts) from it. I have two approaches to do the same task. I would like to know which one should I use for efficiency and which one looks more prone to fail for bigger data samples.

Readline1 gets a list from readline and processes output and writes into the dictionary with key as interface name and values as next three items.

Readline2 uses re module and match the groups and from groups it writes to dictionary keys and values.

input self.output to these functions will be something like this:

```
message = 
"""
Interface 1/1\n\t
    input : 1234\n\t
    output : 3456\n\t
    dropped : 12\n
\n
Interface 1/2\n\t
    input : 7123\n\t
    output : 2345\n\t
    dropped : 31\n\t
"""

def ReadLine1(self):
    lines = self.output.splitlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "Interface" in line:
            valuelist = []
            for i in [1,2,3]:
                valuelist.append((lines[index+i].split(':'))[1].strip())
            self.IFlist[line.split()[1]] = valuelist
    return self.IFlist

def Readline2(self):
    #print repr(self.output)
    n = re.compile(r"\n*Interface (./.)\n\s*input : ([0-9]+)\n\s*output : ([0-9]+)\n\s*dropped : ([0-9]+)",re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    blocks = self.output.split('\n\n')
    for block in blocks:
        m_object = re.match(n, block)
        self.IFlist[m_object.group(1)] = [m_object.group(i) for i in (2,3,4)]
```

Comment: I think this is more a codereview.stackexchange.com question, since you're asking for general comments on your code rather than a specific question.

Comment: in any case, i like the second option much better, it's a "higher level" way of describing your problem -- it's easier to tell reading your code what the regex is doing rather than using split and index. also the list comprehension is more pythonic as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your methods use specific aspects of the format to achieve the parsing you are trying to do, and if that format was changed / broken one of the methods could also break...

For example if you added a space in the empty line between the two entries (which you cannot see) then the `blocks = self.output.split('\n\n')` would fail to find two consecutive newline characters and the regex version would miss out on the second entry:

```
{'1/1': ['1234', '3456', '13']}
```

Or if you added an extra newline between `input` and `output` like this:

```
Interface 1/2
    input : 7123
    output : 2345

    dropped : 31
```

The regex `\s*` would deal with the extra space fine but the non-regex parsing would assume that `lines[index+i].split(':')` has an indice `[1]` so it would raise an IndexError with that data

Or if you added some extra space at the end of any line then the regex would fail to see the newline right after the content and `re.match(n, lock)` would return `None` so the next line would raise an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Or if you changed `Interface` to `interface` for one of the entries (no longer capital `I`) then the regex would raise the same error as above but the non-regex would simply ignore that entry.

While I was testing it I found that the regex was easier to mess up with small edits to the sample `message`, but I also found that the version I made using a generator expression and `str.partition` was significantly more robust then both of them:

```
def readline3():
    gen_lines = (line for line in self.output.splitlines()
                        if line and not line.isspace())
    try:
        while True: #ended when next() throws a StopIteration
            start,_,key = next(gen_lines).partition(" ")
            if start == "Interface":
                IFlist[key] = [next(gen_lines).rpartition(" : ")[2]
                                for _ in "123"]
    except StopIteration: # reached end of output
        return self.IFlist
```

This succeeded in every case mentioned above and a few more, and since the only method this is relying on is `str.partition` which alway returns a 3 item tuple there is nothing to raise any unexpected errors unless `self.output` is something other then a string.

Also running a benchmark using `timeit` your `readline1` consistently was faster then `readline2` and my `readline3` was usually slightly more then `readline1`:

```
#using the default 1000000 loops using 'message'
<function readline1 at 0x100756f28>
11.225649802014232
<function readline2 at 0x1057e3950>
14.838601427007234
<function readline3 at 0x1057e39d8>
11.693351223017089
```